# why can't I throw any more pain au chocolats?

Tags: candy-box-2

I had gotten the game save as text, so I could change my number of pain au chocolats. I saw something that said, 'wishingWellWeArePainAuChocolating=false', so I changed it to true, wondering what would happen. After that, I re-saved, and went to the wishing well, and now I can't throw any more pain au chocolats in there. I click the button and nothing happens. I know it's my fault, but I was wondering whether there's any way that I could reverse the effects, or if anyone knows what happened.

Comment: And, yes, I did try to change it back to 'false.'

Comment: Could you include a picture?

Answer (score -1):

If changing it back to false didn't do anything, try once more, make sure you have the right line, and load it. If it still doesn't work, you might have to reload or restart your game.